# Detecting element over a link

Tags: jointjs

I would like to detect when an element released over a link.

Thank you for your help.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3ZF2.png)

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use paper triggered events.

```
paper.on('cell:pointerup', function(evt, x, y) { 
})
```

cell:pointerup or cell:mouseout will work for your requirement.

Check this tutorial http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Paper:events